# Getting product page moved to new link prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to get the link of the product pages in prestashop. After going through the product class I found the function getLink() and using that I get a link but when I try to go to that link I get an error that page moved to a new link. How to solve this? Following below are the statements I am using to get the links.

```
  $product = new Product(4);
  $link = $product->getLink();
```

Comment: can you paste the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->context->link->getProductLink($product_id);
```

If this doesn't work, try following:

```
$linkObj = new Link();
$productLink = $linkObj->getProductLink($product_id);
```

Comment: This would  provide a working but incomplete link (category and ean are missing in the url .. see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this to get it to work with Prestashop 1.7:

```
$identifier = $product['id_product'] . '-' . $product['id_product_attribute'];
$url = $this->context->link->getProductLink($identifier);`
```

I checked the `getProductLink()` method in the `Link` class and found that it doesn't actually add the attribute id by its self.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to programmatically get a proper rewritten product link that includes rewritten category and product EAN code in the URL.

Of course you'll need to have $**id_product** and $**id_lang** variables properly set :

```
$link = new Link();
$prod = new Product($id_product);
$catRewrite = Category::getLinkRewrite((int)$prod->id_category_default, $id_lang);
$url = $link->getProductLink((int)$prod->id, $prod->link_rewrite[$id_lang], $catRewrite, $prod->ean13);
```